# What is returned when Select event fires in Openlayers?

Tags: openlayers

I'm quite new to Openlayers and jscript in general. Using Openlayers 3.9.0.
Can anyone hint where to look up the structure of the 'e' object which is returned when Select event fires?

```
select.on('select',function(e){
  //...
});
```

For example I come across such things `as e.target.getFeatures()`. What else is there in the 'e' object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I have found the list of members at http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.interaction.SelectEvent.html#event:select and http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.MapBrowserEvent.html

Here are a few examples:
e.selected - contans an array of last time selected features.
e.mapBrowserEvent.pixel - contans the pixel at which a click occured.

Answer (score 1):

```
  select.on('select', function(e) {

        e.selected.forEach(function(e){


            // get Feature
            console.log(e);
            // get Properties
            console.log(e.getProperties());
           // get one specific Property
            console.log(e.get('name'));

        });
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/0spfvvhz/

( To inspect the global variable "test" in this jsfiddle example open chrome dev tools and switch frame to "result(fiddle.jshell.net" in the Console tab dropdown as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328963/access-variables-in-jsfiddle-from-javascript-console )